# Multiple port in-line push-in connector?

Tags: electrical, wire, connectors

I've been working in some very tight light fixtures lately, and it was basically impossible to get the wires with wire nuts tucked into the fixture. So I came across [multi-port push-in connectors](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Ideal-33-Orange-In-Sure-3-Port-Connectors-100-Pack-30-1033P/202894310?MERCH=REC-_-PIPHorizontal2_rr-_-202911032-_-202894310-_-N), like this:

```
|-
|-
|-
```

and [in-line butt splice connectors](http://www.idealindustries.ca/products/wire_termination/push-in/spliceline_in-line_wire_connectors.php), like this:

```
-|-
```

Both of these really helped in these tight fixtures. However, what would REALLY be helpful is a combination of those, where the 3 ports were not all facing the same direction. Particularly, something like:

```
-|-
 |-
```

I don't see why that wouldn't be a thing, but I can't seem to find anything like that. Have you ever seen something like this? (even like a 4-port one configured like:

```
-|-
-|-
```

would do the trick!

Comment: These connectors are much bulkier than wire nuts, so it doesn't make any sense that wire nuts wouldn't fit.  Are the wire nuts coming undone on you?

Comment: It's all about the configuration of the wires in the box. Making 180 degree turns to get into the nut is killing me (there are wires coming in from the left of the box, then also going out from the right of the box to another fixture (these are undercabinet LED strips: https://www.homedepot.com/p/GE-Enbrighten-18-in-LED-Direct-Wire-Under-Cabinet-Light-34287/300049737) , and also the wire nuts don't fit along the long side of the fixture between the casing and the transformer, but the push-in connectors do.

Comment: Wires can make sharp turns. Heck, the SE-recommended way to attach to switches and receptacles is a J-hook around the screw.  The instructions say "Arrange the wires inside the fixture between the white plastic driver housing and the exterior metal wall and reattach the cover" and GE clearly intends this to be done with 1-face push connectors, since the drawings show that.   Can you pre-bend the wires before you push them into the box? My point being "don't be bashful about doing that".